# testContainers and Rancher

Tags: intellij-idea, rancher, testcontainers

I have a `Spring Boot` application with integration tests that are using `testContainers`.

Till recently, I used Docker Desktop and was able to easily run the test from within Intellij or from CLI.

Recently I changed my Windows machine to [Rancher desktop](https://rancherdesktop.io/).

Now when trying to run the integration tests `gradle integrationTest` I'm getting this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Previous attempts to find a Docker environment failed. Will not retry. Please see logs and check configuration
> at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:109)
> at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:136)
> at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:178)
> at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.getDockerClient(LazyDockerClient.java:14)
> at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.authConfig(LazyDockerClient.java:12)
> at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:310)

Is there an additional configuration that is needed in Intellij or Rancher or Windows to make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE Feb 2022**: As reported [here](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/4791#issuecomment-1029749857) TestContainers works nicely with Rancher Desktop `1.0.1`.

<del>Based on the following two closed issues - [first](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/4783), [second](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/4791) - in the **testcontainers-java** github, Testcontainers doesn't seem to support Rancher Desktop, at least officially.</del>

Answer (score 6):

In my case, you needed to set it to allow sudo access. You can set it as such

[image]

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me too. It is absolutely unnecessary that `sudo` access is required to be able to boot up containers from testcontainers.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because my Rancher was using containerd. If you also use Rancher Desktop try to switch to dockerd under settings, but first back up the data you have just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running rancher desktop version 1.0.0 on my windows mashine and could get testcontainers to work just by simple adding 'checks.disable=true' in .testcontainers.properties (located under C:\Users<your user>)

Comment: thanks for the post, but this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

updating Rancher Desktop to version 1.0.1 fixed this issue for me